# Remove excel document action pane before saving excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop, vba

I wish to clear document action pane controls before workbook shutdown. So that next time when I open that workbook action pane will not there. Basically I wish to detach action pane before workbook close.

I have tried something like this.

Code snippet

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActionsPane.Clear();
}
```

But it throws exception **Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.ActionsPane'.**

So is there any other way to remove the same.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to clear the ActionPane in the Startup Event?

Hope this helps!

I found the following lines @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/7we49he1(v=vs.100).aspx

> If the user saves the document while the actions pane is visible, the
>   actions pane is visible every time the document is opened, whether or
>   not the actions pane contains any controls. If you want to control
>   when it appears, call the Clear method of the ActionsPane field in the
>   Startup event handler of ThisDocument or ThisWorkbook to ensure that
>   the actions pane is not visible when the document is opened.

Comment: If I clear actionPane on the startup event it will first load action pane and then after it will clear the action pane. but I don't want to load action pane only.